# How to update changes to Amazon ec2 database using Visual Studio AWS Toolkit

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Here's the setup: I have a web application created in Visual Studio that uses a SQL Server database (.mdf). I have published this website to an amazon ec2 instance using the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. The toolkit uses the project settings during deployment. So the first time I deployed the application with the database, it deployed just fine. But since then I have made changes to the local database, and would like those changes to also be on the deployed database, but when I try to re-deploy the application it comes back with a SQL error, "Table already exists.", etc. This is because the scripts in the "Package/Publish SQL" properties try to make the database from scratch. I need the new changes to the local database reflected in the deployed database. Deleting the deployed database and re-creating it is not an option, as we would like to keep the data in it. I'm looking for a sort of way to merge the two: add any missing tables/columns and data. How would I go about doing that? Would I have to write my own custom SQL script to update the database, or is there an entirely different way that's better? If the SQL script is the best option, could I get an example? I know close to nothing about SQL.

In the end what we're looking for is to be able to hit the "Deploy" button in the Amazon Toolkit, and the entire project (including the database) is updated.

Comment: You might be asking for a little too much.  Have you tried out Amazon RDS yet?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I realize this is quite a bit; I'm in way over my head with this one. I haven't looked at RDS yet, because we're currently looking for other options as RDS is a bit expensive.